# Is there a way to remove blank pages before a new \chapter{}?

Tags: chapters, page-breaking, overleaf, templates, report

I'm using the AAU Report Template to write my Project but every time I \include{} a new chapter it creates a new chapter. I've tried using \input{} rather than \include{} but still keeps the blank page. My documentclass is report type and I've tried changing it from doubleside to oneside, removing the blank page but at the cost of aligning all text towards the right when I want it to be right and left. My document setup code can be found below. I would really appreciate your help.

```
%  A simple AAU report template.
%  2015-05-08 v. 1.2.0
%  Copyright 2010-2015 by Jesper Kjær Nielsen <jkn@es.aau.dk>
%
%  This is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
%  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
%  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
%  (at your option) any later version.
%
%  This is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
%  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
%  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
%  GNU General Public License for more details.
%
%  You can find the GNU General Public License at <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
%
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Language, Encoding and Fonts
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Select encoding of your inputs. Depends on
% your operating system and its default input
% encoding. Typically, you should use
%   Linux  : utf8 (most modern Linux distributions)
%            latin1 
%   Windows: ansinew
%            latin1 (works in most cases)
%   Mac    : applemac
% Notice that you can manually change the input
% encoding of your files by selecting "save as"
% an select the desired input encoding. 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Make latex understand and use the typographic
% rules of the language used in the document.
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
% Use the palatino font
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}         % Palatino needs more leading (space between lines)
% Choose the font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Graphics and Tables
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% load a colour package
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{aaublue}{RGB}{33,26,82}% dark blue
% The standard graphics inclusion package
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Set up how figure and table captions are displayed
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
  font=footnotesize,% set font size to footnotesize
  labelfont=bf % bold label (e.g., Figure 3.2) font
}
% Make the standard latex tables look so much better
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
% Enable the use of frames around, e.g., theorems
% The framed package is used in the example environment
\usepackage{framed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Mathematics
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Defines new environments such as equation,
% align and split 
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Adds new math symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
% Use theorems in your document
% The ntheorem package is also used for the example environment
% When using thmmarks, amsmath must be an option as well. Otherwise \eqref doesn't work anymore.
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page Layout
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Change margins, papersize, etc of the document
\usepackage[
  inner=28mm,% left margin on an odd page
  outer=41mm,% right margin on an odd page
  ]{geometry}
% Modify how \chapter, \section, etc. look
% The titlesec package is very configureable
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}

% Clear empty pages between chapters
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  {\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage

% Change the headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %delete everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove the horizontal line in the header
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark} %even page - chapter title
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase\rightmark} %uneven page - section title
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} %page number on all pages
% Do not stretch the content of a page. Instead,
% insert white space at the bottom of the page
\raggedbottom
% Enable arithmetics with length. Useful when
% typesetting the layout.
\usepackage{calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
  bibencoding=utf8
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib/mybib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Misc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Add bibliography and index to the table of
% contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
% Add the command \pageref{LastPage} which refers to the
% page number of the last page
\usepackage{lastpage}
% Add todo notes in the margin of the document
\usepackage[
%  disable, %turn off todonotes
  colorinlistoftodos, %enable a coloured square in the list of todos
  textwidth=\marginparwidth, %set the width of the todonotes
  textsize=scriptsize, %size of the text in the todonotes
  ]{todonotes}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hyperlinks
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Enable hyperlinks and insert info into the pdf
% file. Hypperref should be loaded as one of the 
% last packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfpagelabels=true,%
    plainpages=false,%
    pdfauthor={Author(s)},%
    pdftitle={Title},%
    pdfsubject={Subject},%
    bookmarksnumbered=true,%
    colorlinks=false,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,% you should probably change this to black before printing
    urlcolor=blue,%
    pdfstartview=FitH%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is probably due to the `openright` option of your document class; it forces new chapters to begin on an odd page, and if the previous chapter ends on an odd page, the following will leavethe nextcpage, which is even, blank in order to begin on an odd page.

Answer (score 1):

You call `\documentclass{...,openright}` which makes all chapters start on right-hand pages. (Or perhaps to be on the safe side specify `openany`).

Remove that class option!

Answer (score 0):

Please always add the full compilable [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and make sure you narrow your question and example to a specific problem.

I reduced the example below to a selected packages, which demonstrate the solution. I think in the ultimate problem in the original file was to apply an empty style to pages containing chapter titles, hence the custom macro definition `\clearemptydoublepage`. I would suggest the following solutions based on [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)

```
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
```

It substitutes the `plain` style with `empty` on pages containing chapter titles. With this solution, you no longer need to mess with redefining `\clear(double)page`.

As to your question, by default LaTeX applies `\clearpage` before each `\chapter`. If `openright` is set, LaTeX applies `\cleardoublepage`, instead. With the solution above, removing `openright` will sort your problem.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % For \patchcmd{}{}{}{}
\usepackage[
  inner=28mm,% left margin on an odd page
  outer=41mm,% right margin on an odd page
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %delete everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove the horizontal line in the header
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark} %even page - chapter title
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase\rightmark} %uneven page - section title
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} %page number on all pages
% Do not stretch the content of a page. Instead,
% insert white space at the bottom of the page
\raggedbottom
% Enable arithmetics with length. Useful when
% typesetting the layout.

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % For dummy texts


\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\kant[1-2]

\chapter{Two}
\kant[1-6]

\chapter{Three}
\kant[1-5]

\chapter{Four}
\kant[1-5]

\end{document}
```